# How to correct the footer in Wordpress Theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, css, wordpress-theming, footer

**Problem:**

I have just tranferred my hosting to another in wordpress but when I open my website all looks well in the current theme except the footer has some problem in displaying 4 columns grid in it showed in screenshot. 
[The Wordpress theme footer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrmqq.jpg)

**Looking for:**

Please help me to correct it that where the problem is exactly and how to resolve it. Thank you.

Comment: Did you use a specific template ? If yes, have you check the options ?

Comment: Yes they are exactly the same as they were before. Should I have to reinstall theme and configure everything again?

Comment: I think it will be the "final" solution. Try to compare your old and new table "wp-options" to be sure you have the good configuration first